# Store values in multidimensional array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using a `while loop`

```
      $i = 0;
      $arr = array();
      while($get_key1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_key))
      {
        $busid = $get_key1['busid'];
        $get_key2 = mysql_query("select * from `route` where `busid`='$busid'") or die(mysql_error());

        while($get_key3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_key2))
        {
            $arr[$i] = $get_key3['routid'];
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($arr);
        }
        echo "<hr/>";
        $i++;
      }
```

This inner loop gives three values, `1,3,4` and when itereates again then it gives values `1,4` I want to create a multi dimensional array as

```
array(array(1,3,4),array(1,4))
```

but the above code gives the result as :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 1
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 4
)
```

How can I store the values through while loop in multi dimensional array

Comment: change `$arr[$i]` to `$arr[$i][]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$i` as outer array and let create index of inner array itself.

```
while($get_key3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_key2))
{
    $arr[$i][] = $get_key3['routid']; // simple change
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Disha it saved me